# How to use velocity with remote Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, testing, meteor, meteor-velocity

if i start meteor just by `>$ meteor` and therefore a local mongodb velocity runs my tests without problems. but if i try to connect to a remote mongodb testing fails `>$ MONGO_URL=<mongostring> meteor`

velocity tells me, that a mirror is running and when i go there with `>$ meteor` all is fine but with `>$ MONGO_URL=<mongostring> meteor` i just get this error message http://pastebin.com/zaRvUs6F

what am i doing wrong? i would be happy to not use the remote db at all for testing but i don't want to restart the server with different configurations to test, i want the tests fly by, the way its supposed to be.

//edit:

maybe its a bug? https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity/issues/347

Answer (score 0):

If this is a blocker, you can give a try to my testing framework: https://github.com/taromero/latte.

It doesn't use mirrors, so it doesn't matter where you point your app's DB, it will always work on the specified testing DB (default being `mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor_latte`, but it can be configured).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll definitely try to look into this.